# Python turtle moves up and right but not left and down

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am coding a snake game in Python.

I have `from turtle import Screen, Turtle` and I have the starting positions

```
STARTING_POSITIONS = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
MOVE_DISTANCE = 20
UP = 90
DOWN = 270
LEFT = 180
RIGHT = 0
```

and then

```
screen.onkey(snake.up, "Up")
screen.onkey(snake.down, "Down")
screen.onkey(snake.left, "Left")
screen.onkey(snake.right, "Right")
screen.listen()
```

Up and right behave as expected but not left and down.

The snake does not respond to

for example, `snake.speed(3)`, when I try to slow it down either.

Answer (score 1):

`turtle.Turtle.up()`, `.left()`, `.right()` and `.down()` don't do what you think they do. `.up()` and `.down()` put the pen up and down and don't affect direction and `.left()` and `.right()` don't immediately snap the turtle to a certain direction, they turn it by a specific angle which must be specified.

Instead of doing this you should use `turtle.Turtle.setheading()` to your constants, which would look like the following:

```
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.setheading(UP), "Up")
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.setheading(DOWN), "Down")
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.setheading(LEFT), "Left")
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.setheading(RIGHT), "Right")
screen.listen()
```

Note that this sets which way they are facing but does not move them in that direction. If you want to do that , create your own function for each direction and use that, so for left that would look like:

```
def move_left():
    snake.setheading(LEFT)
    snake.forward(5)

screen.onkey(move_left, "Left")
screen.listen()
```

Comment: I agree with your nice analysis of the problem, but it doesn't explain why `right` worked for the OP and `left` didn't.  Looking at the OP's code, both should have failed due to lack of an angle argument!

Comment: Figured this out, thanks both. The right answer is a combination of both. The angle argument I had defined as a constant: UP = 90
DOWN = 270
LEFT = 180
RIGHT = 0; the issue is that I had forgotten about the constraint that up is not down and left is not right...